# Font-Awesome: Trying to make this thing work with WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, debian, apache2, font-awesome

I am trying to make Font-Awesome working with my self-hosted WordPress blog (debian machine)

What I've tried so far:

Insert this in /usr/share/wordpress/.htaccess and\or /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf and\or /etc/apache2/proxy.conf

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>                                                                                         
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">                                                        
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                                                       
    </FilesMatch>                                                                                            
</IfModule>
```

I've tried inserting this in theme.css and\or custom CSS and\or manually edit via Chrome debug console.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.2');  
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.2') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.2') format('woff'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.2') format('truetype'), url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.5.2#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;  font-style: normal;
}
```

I am now sure that I've tried all combinations, and all the imports of font-awesome.css and font awesome font are all 4.5.2 version

What I have to do to make this thing works?

My website link is http://gun-gummybears.it/?page_id=414 and as you can see, font-awesome isn't working.

Comment: That link seems NSFW...

Comment: No, it is not.. sorry should've said that :D .. it is just a "community" blog, we share our idiot things.

Comment: Oh, okay. Ha ha.. Could you just disable all the posts, so that we can check?

Comment: It is often helpful to include screenshots so people don't have to visit external sites.

Comment: i've edited the link, you can check here:  http://gun-gummybears.it/?page_id=414

Comment: I can attach a screenshot... but how people can check my css without going to my website?

Comment: @blast1987 Paste it here in your question. Are you familiar with the concept of an MCVE?

Comment: @TylerH we'll i think i've already pasted everything necessary in the post, except this:  <link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css' href='http://gun-gummybears.it/wp-content/themes/themeforest-6589637-dw-fixel-responsive-wordpress-blog-theme/assets/css/font-awesome.css?ver=4.5.2; type='text/css' media='all' />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that you might find useful. It looks like some stuff wasn't arrange properly. Give this a shot.

This is what I've found:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# webfont mime types
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType font/truetype                  ttf
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff              woff

# webfonts and svg:
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

If you look closely the order of the tags FilesMatch and IfModule have been switched. We've also used AddType for each file extension.

This text should be placed in your .htaccess file within the root Wordpress directory.

Here's the source for this:
https://gist.github.com/WheresAlice/843983

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help i've tried your solution but it didn't work... font awesome is displaying white squares as always...

Comment: @blast1987 Well darn. Why don't you just include the font with <link> in the head?

Comment: What you mean ?  I'm including the font awesome css in the head:  <link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='http://gun-gummybears.it/wp-content/themes/themeforest-6589637-dw-fixel-responsive-wordpress-blog-theme/assets/css/font-awesome.css?ver=4.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />   how can i include the font here?

Comment: the font is inside the .css .. using @font-face

Comment: Sorry, you're doing it right. I wasn't thinking about it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be marked as solved and what posted Ryan Scott Cady solved my problem.

But there was another error, i had a plugin that was overrding the FontFamily on every font on my website, i removed this plugin and everything went fine.

Just to let you know the bugged plugin was something named "twitch embed plugin"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the header.php file (or where-ever you keep your header code) and paste the embed code below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```